# How does Spring convert Java to JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot project, I just return a list directly. Then I can see the JSON response in Postman. I didn't do anything to convert the Java object to JSON. How does it work? Is JSON the default way to exchange data for Java?

Here is an controller example.

```java
@GetMapping("/")
@Secured({"ROLE_ANONYMOUS", "ROLE_REGULAR"})
List<Project> allProducts() {
    return projectService.getAllProjects();
}
```

Here is the dependency part of my pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the kind of answer you're looking for, but that's Spring Boot doing it by default and automatically when Jackson is in the classpath.

Comment: _"Is JSON the default way to exchange data for Java?"_ No. This is your browser sending an `Accept` header with value `application/json` and Spring Boot supporting this through the Jackson library. If Spring Boot didn't have access to Jackson (or you had customized the supported content-types) in your controller, you would have gotten an HTTP error 406

Answer (score 0):

> How does it work?

By default Spring will use Jackson to convert your object graph to JSON.

> Is JSON the default way to exchange data for java?

No, it isn't.  Java doesn't define a default way to exchange data.

Answer (score 0):

The DispatchServlet process calls HttpMessageConverter for serialization